# linux find prune

Tags: string, search

I am trying to exclude two directories; vntvdone and downloading, but for some reason, my command still goes in there and outputs the file within it:

```
find -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.VOB' -o -path './downloading' -prune -o -path './vntvdone' -prune
```

I am also running into problems where if a folder/directory that has .mp4 in it, it also gets treated as a file as well... how can we do this search only for files and not folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to use ! than use `prune`. I've assumed the starting path for find is '.'  The example omits it.

```
find . \( -type d -a ! -name 'downloading' -a ! -name 'vntdone' -a ! -name '.' \) -o -name \*.avi -o -name \*.mkv -o -name \*.mp4 -o -name \*.VOB
```

Comment: here's what I got when using your suggestion:  Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name `./downloading'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ `./downloading''.

Comment: Sorry - edited answer now. I did test it - but using different names.

Comment: we're getting closer, however, it still returns ./ with no file names that ends with the extensions i'm looking for... can we not have it return ./?

Comment: Ah yes - remove the quotes from the *.filename names. It prevents the file expansion that the `find` command needs. Answer edited.

Comment: I've checked - it works this end. can you paste the command you used so I can cross check?

Comment: i put this inside a bash script, and then i have it echo out the results  for FILENAME in $moviefile
        do
     echo $FILENAME

Comment: i even tried this directly to the shell, and it gives back a . first then the file names with the extensions i want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26711/discussion-between-suspectus-and-thevoipman)

Comment: Hello, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't your suggestions also pick up folder that has ".mp4" in the folder name as well? I'm getting mixed results till now that this does happen.

Comment: Bear in mind that `!` does not *prune*: when it matches a directory it doesn't keep `find` from descending into it. Therefore a general translation between the two isn't so easy.