# Using Find Command with a RegEx for the Search String

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I wrote a command that successfully returns all PDF files that contain the keyword "Font":

```
find /my/path/PDFFiles/  -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec grep -H "Font" '{}' ';'
```

There are some limitations with this command that I'd like to overcome.

**Questions**

1. How would I use a RegEx for my search string where I am currently doing just "Font"
2. How can I adjust the command above to return all filenames where the keyword "Font" does not exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `grep` supports regular expressions out of the box. So just get rid of the `""`. For example, if you want "dont" or "font"

```
find /my/path/PDFFiles/  -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec grep -H "[df]ont" '{}' ';'
```

2) `grep` also allows you to exclude entries with a `-v` command. So to exclude 'Font' try:

```
find /my/path/PDFFiles/  -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec grep -vH "Font" '{}' ';'
```

You can also use `find`s `prune` option as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565660/linux-find-prune)

Comment: [df]ont, unquoted, will fail under zsh with the error `zsh: no matches found: [df]ont` (never executing the command). Quoted is always safer (but especially it wards off danger in the case that either ? or * are present in your expression, vulnerable to interpretation by the shell.)

Comment: Thank you @kampu! I've updated my answer accordingly. I've actually just switched to zsh but foolishly only checked it ran in bash! I'll know for next time. Good point on the "quoted is always safer".